# CakePHP help with read()

Tags: cakephp

I am following the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1536/Creating-Post-Views) and modifying it to fit my site's needs.  I am having a little trouble with my view function.

```
    function view($id = null)
    {
        $this->Article->articleid = $id;
        $this->set('article', $this->Article->read());
    }
```

This line does not work, I get this error: Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Article.id' in 'where clause' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 681]

However, I got it to work with `$this->set('article', $this->Article->find('first' , array('conditions' => array('Article.articleid' => $id))));`

My schema for articles is

- articleid
- userid
- title
- text

The query has WHERE `Article`.`id` = '1'
however, thats wrong. It should be articleid instead of id

Anyway I can change this so I could use read()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you specified inside the Article model that `var $primaryKey = 'articleid';` ?

From [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1061/primaryKey):

> Each table normally has a primary key, id. You may change which field name the model uses as its primary key. This is common when setting CakePHP to use an existing database table.